# Conversion of boost::optional to bool

Tags: c++, boost, type-conversion, boost-optional

How I can prevent the last line of this code from compiling?

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::optional<int> int_opt;
    int_opt opt = 0;
    bool x = opt;  // <- I do not want this to compile
}
```

The last line doesn't examine `opt`'s contained int value, but instead compiles as a type conversion to bool, and doesn't seem to be what the user intended.

The safe bool idiom seems to be relevant here?

Comment: What do you mean _something like_? Describe in English what you want. The code obviously does not describe what you want. So how should we know?

Comment: you can't, `boost::optional` implements `operator!` and this is why the last line above compiles. You can't even derive from this to hide that operator - you need to fix your code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The whole point of `boost::optional` is to enable code like this:

```
void func(boost::optional<int> optionalArg)
{
    if (optionalArg) {
       doSomething(*optionalArg);
    }
}
```

So the implicit conversion to `bool` is a feature, and should not be prevented from compiling.

Comment: This is not what safe bool idiom tries to solve? (http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html)

Comment: @dimba: Naturally safe bool idiom doesn't prevent using the value in purely boolean contexts.

Comment: @UncleBens - indeed, changing x type in last line from bool to int causes to compilation error.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is correct. implicit conversion to `bool` does indeed fail to build. But conversion to bool in boolean contexts, works. I don't know if that means that boolean contexts means the compiler considers them explicit. But proof as @Andrzej said https://wandbox.org/permlink/d5gAYFx3iEK8uaxy

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you describe used to be the case for the older versions of Boost. Ever since 1.56 release `boost::optional` has an explicit conversion to `bool` and the code that you show does not compile anymore (exactly the way you wanted). [See here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tk8XyjqRzqlOptmf).

Comment: The "See here" link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `optional` then you need to be able to determine if it's set before using it. The way this is implemented is with the (effectively bool) conversion.

It doesn't in my mind follow that the user didn't want what's actually written there: They should know that it's an `optional` and that they're checking it for validity.

Since the conversion is a built in part of `boost::optional` I'm not aware of any way to directly remove it.

You could of course implement a wrapper class for your particular `int` need that provides just the parts of the `optional` interface that you want, possibly with an explicit function that checks validity.

Alternately you could always use `template<class T> inline T const* get_pointer ( optional<T> const& opt ) ;` or its non-const version when working with `optional`s to make it explicit what's happening.