# Boost Optional implicit conversion to bool?

Tags: c++, boost, googletest, boost-optional

I'm reading some code and I came across something I do not understand.
Its about testing if a Boost::optional value is initialised or not. It uses the gtest framework which provides the `ASSERT_TRUE()` macro.

```
#include "gtest\gtest.h"

void test() {
    boost::optional<someClass> opt = someFunc();
    ASSERT_TRUE(!!opt);
}
```

Why do I need the `!!` before `opt`? Is a `boost::optional` not implicitly converted to a bool, which is needed by the macro? I thought it would be enough to use `ASSERT_TRUE(opt)` to check if opt holds a correct value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is a `boost::optional` not impicit converted to a bool

No, it's not. Its conversion operator to `bool` is marked `explicit`, but your testing framework needs something that's implicitly convertible. You should see the problem with plain `bool test = opt;` too: that should fail to compile.

Comment: I understand, but if I read this post right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923384/conversion-of-boostoptional-to-bool, it is implicit converted? Has this changed?

Comment: @Suv `if(my_optional)` will compile even if the conversion operator is `explicit` because that's a [contextual conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Contextual_conversions). Also, depending on the version of Boost and whether you have c++11 enabled etc., `optional` might use the safe bool idiom for the bool conversion, which is also an implicit conversion, but prevents compilation of some questionable uses.